# How do I create a top-level button menu in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm fairly new to android development, although I've known java for quite some time.

What I'm trying to do is make a dichotomy-eske information portal app. I would like it to be visually simple, however, so I thought it would be nice to create a clean button menu as a top-level menu.

For reference, I'm looking for something similar to the menu system of Angry Birds or the like *functionally*. I know they use some sort of OpenGL system that I'm unfamiliar with as I've just started and I'm not trying to make a game in the first place.

What I mean by this is I just want to have a - lets say - 6 button menu as the main menu that once you press the first button, it goes into a sub-menu and then from there you can make another selection into a specific pane.

Ex. The first 6 options are: vegetables, fruit, meat, etc.
You click vegetables and you get a list view of vegetables.
You press carrot and are now have a page with pictures of carrots, and a text description.

I am trying to figure out how to best do this because my understanding of fragments is somewhat limited as I continue to dig around. I'm unsure of if I should have multiple activities and program each button to move between them for this kind of behavior or if I should use fragments to make this more seamless.

Basically, I get how to lay out the individual pages, but I'm unsure of how I should structurally be programming the transitions. Through the three stages should it be:

Activity ---> Activity ---> Activity?
Activity ---> Activity with 2 fragments(list and content)?
Activity that opens a fragment containing child fragments of the list and content?

I'm trying to use a ListFragment but I don't know if I'm just making this harder than it needs to be.

Thanks for any help, I know I'm probably overthinking this a bit.

EDIT: Just TL;DR because I know that was a lot of explaination:

I'm wondering the best method to create a 6-button menu whether that be through a chain of activities, a fragment like a ListFragment or what might be most commonly used. The kind of menu I imagine isn't unfrequently used, but I couldn't really find documentation as to how to replicate it.

Comment: You should spend some time reading through Material Design Patters(it may help with your architecture).  If you are new, I would stick with Activities and always keep in mind that it is considered best practice to use fragments. If you achieve everything through activites then try converting them to fragments individually. Fragments do not make life easier in the short run, but deff in the long run.    https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-combined-patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want the user to be able to press the *Back* button to get back to the previous view, you want to use an `Activity` for that view.

Though, with a list like you described, [master/detail](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html) flow is usually a good paradigm. In this case the navigational flow would change depending on the screen width. If you can fit both the list and the content, they would each be a `Fragment` in a single `Activity` (not needing a `Back` button). Otherwise, you can display the same two fragments, but this time they are each displayed in a separate `Activity` (with a `Back` button in the detail `Activity` to get back to the list).

As for the top-level six button list you described, you may want to consider a [navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) instead. In this case, a list for each of the six items would be displayed inside a `Fragment`, which will be replaced depending on which navigation item is selected. Then you can manage whether or not to display a detail `Fragment` as described previously.

Android Studio actually provides templates for each of these layouts (File > New > Activity > [Master/Detail Flow] [Navigation Drawer Activity]), but you will have to make the two work together on your own.

Though this is an extremely simplified take. There are various use-cases for fragments and activities, so use whatever makes sense for your application.